# What is the fastest way of reading the standard output stream of a process

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know the fastest way of reading the standard output stream of a process here is my example code. When reading large amounts of data from the standard output stream is slow.

```
 Dim myprocess As New Process

 Dim programOutput As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

 With myprocess
    .StartInfo.FileName = "C:\myconsoleapp.exe"
    .StartInfo.Arguments = "my args"
    .StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    .Start()
 End With

 While Not myprocess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream

     programOutput.Add(myprocess.StandardOutput.ReadLine())

 End While

 myprocess.Dispose()
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't relate to an actual problem.

Comment: How so reading large amounts of data is slow I would like to know how to improve the speeds.

Comment: SO is not a place for getting that kind of advice. It is a place for getting help with specific issues, i.e. "I'm trying to do X, I'm trying to do it like this, this is what happens when I try, how do I fix it". Your code is working so there is no issue. Your question is a worthwhile question but this is not the place to ask it.

Comment: I'm not really sure there is too much at this end to make more efficient.  Perhaps the slowness you're seeing in large data sets is due to the output of myconsoleapp.exe.

Comment: Other than that perhaps the only thing else to try is ReadtToEnd() rather than each line in a loop